# PhpStorm HTML shortcuts

Tags: phpstorm

I would like to use HTML shortcuts in PhpStorm in a way I know from other editors.

Example:

```
a.test.test2
```

should be resolved to

```
<a class="test test2"></a>
```

Is there any way to activate this? The live templates seem to work in a different way.

Comment: It's called **Emmet** and it works just fine in `.html` files. Check if Emmet is enabled in Settings (should be by default) and ensure that you are using correct expand key (in case if you have changed it).

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried the wrong expand key, now everything is working fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **Emmet and** it works just fine in `.html` files.

Check if Emmet is enabled for HTML (it is by default) and ensure that you are using correct expand key (in case if you have changed it; by default it should be <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

**Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet**

[image]